Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++
I am using infobip_mobilemessaging  for chatbot and i am using its push notifications too.
So, the scenerio is when on tap on the notification it should check first if user is logged in or not. if it is logged in then it will show the chatbot, and when navigating back from chatbot it should navigate to home screen. if it is not logged in then it should display the login screen.
There is a function of ontappednotification
 InfobipMobilemessaging.on(
        LibraryEvent.notificationTapped,
        (Message message) {
          _handleNotificationTap(message);

          log('LibraryEvent.notificationTapped');
          isNotificationTap = true;


        },
      );
static void _handleNotificationTap(Message message) {

    if (message.chat == true) {
      bool? isUserLoggedIn = checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() as bool?;
      log('isUserLoggedIn $isUserLoggedIn');

      if (isUserLoggedIn??false) {
        log("Navigating to chat page");
        isNotificationTap == false;
        goRouter.push(AppPaths.chatPage);
      } else {
        log("Navigating to welcome screen");
        goRouter.go(AppPaths.welcomeScreen);
      }
    }
  }


but it is not working for me, it print the log but checking the _handleNotificationTap method.
A/c to the doc of infobip, i found this  and it says to create the Callback Activity.
here is what i done
created an activity named NotificationCallbackActivity.java
package com.example.open_banking;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class NotificationCallbackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String prefsName = "com.example.open_banking.PREFS";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(prefsName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isUserLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isUserLoggedIn", false);
        Intent intent;
        if (isUserLoggedIn) {
            // User is logged in, navigate to ChatPage
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("navigateTo", "/ChatPage");
        } else {
            // User is not logged in, navigate to LoginScreen
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("navigateTo", "/LoginScreen");
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

MainActivity.java
package com.example.open_banking;
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

MyApplication.java

package com.example.open_banking;

import android.app.Application;
import org.infobip.mobile.messaging.MobileMessaging;
import org.infobip.mobile.messaging.NotificationSettings;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        NotificationSettings notificationSettings = new NotificationSettings.Builder(this)
            .withCallbackActivity(NotificationCallbackActivity.class)  // Use your callback activity
            .build();

        new MobileMessaging.Builder(this)
            .withDisplayNotification(notificationSettings)
            .build();
    }
}



and updated the AndriodManifest file
<application
        android:label="ONE"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        tools:replace="android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback">  <!-- Added tools:replace attribute -->

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Deep linking -->
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="com.infobip.mobilemessaging" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationCallbackActivity"
            android:exported="true"/>
        
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>



And when i tap on notification in terminal this statement prints
 Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: infobip_mobilemessaging/broadcast. Response ID: 85

please help me to fix the issue.
